# Avoid unnecessary spaces in far manager built-int editor

Tags: windows, editor, far

I tried the far manager and its editor for programming.
I've notice that the editor seems like ignore end of lines, because **I can put the cursor in anywhere inside the file**, even in places I have not written, and **if I press a key, far puts spaces until this position.**

It's very annoying, there is some configuration or extension to avoid this?

Example:
* = space
$ = cursor

```
#include<iostream>                $
using*namespace*std;
```

Now pressing some key:

```
#include<iostream>****************f
using*namespace*std;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the editor (F4 in la file), press ALT + SHIFT + F9 and deselect [ ] Cursor beyond end of line.